# Updating different sheets of Apache POI Workbook using multiple threads

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, apache-poi

I have a for loop which i would like to run parallelly.

```
        if (platform != null) {
            for (final String p : platform) {
                log.info("Platform " + p);
                executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            runService(p, config, url, title, report);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE,TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        }
```

The runService method for each platform creates a new sheet for the same workbook.

I have read on other stackoverflow questions that apache poi workbook does not support multithreading on the same workbook object .I have made those methods as synchronized which are updating the sheet of the workbook. This solves all the apache-poi errors which I was getting but still would like to know is there a better way to handle this situation.

Comment: What do you think you are gaining by trying to do things in parallel rather than just in series?

Comment: @Gagravarr in my case the operations happening in runService take around 24 mins to complete and we have around 15 platforms to test, so basically try to reduce the total execution time